# Count how many times new line is present?

Tags: regex, c#-4.0, count

For example,

```
string="help/nsomething/ncrayons"
```

Output:

```
String word count is: 3
```

This is what I have but the program is looping though the method several times and it looks like I am only getting the last string created.  Here's the code block:

```
Regex regx = new Regex(@"\w+([-+.]\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
MatchCollection matches = regx.Matches(output);
//int counte = 0;
foreach (Match match in matches)
{
    //counte = counte + 1;
    links = links + match.Value + '\n';
    if (links != null)
    {
        string myString = links;
        string[] words = Regex.Split(myString, @"\n");

        word_count.Text = words.Length.ToString();
    }

}
```

It is `\n` for newline.

Comment: You are mixing \n and /n throughout your question. We could assume that you mean \n for newline but it would be better if you could be clear about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if regex is a must for your case but you could use `split`:

```
string myString = "help/nsomething/ncrayons";
string[] separator = new string[] { "/n" };
string[] result = myString.Split(separator, StringSplitOptions.None);
MessageBox.Show(result.Count().ToString());
```

Another way using regex:

```
string myString = "help/nsomething/ncrayons";
string[] words = Regex.Split(myString, @"/n");
word_count.Text = words.Length;
```

Comment: I get this error when I try to use "Count" as you have it here: Error 3 'System.Array' does not contain a definition for 'Count' and no extension method 'Count' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Array' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: @Jason it works fine for me on VS 2010, .net 3.5 and 4.0 what framework are you targeting ?

Comment: i am using 4.0. I using this code and it does not like it: word_count.Text = result.Count().ToString();

Comment: @Jason i have just tried it on both 3.5 and 4.0 and it works just fine to update the text box with the count.

Comment: @Jason - Make sure you have `using System.Linq;`, or simply use `result.Length`.

Comment: @Jason updated with a regex example since it was bothering me.

Comment: Oops, since I am using Regex to get the values of the string initially, I have several dozen data values but I only get 6 returned so I can't use split :(

Comment: @Jason perhaps you want to post some code so I can understand better what is going on. Because given your above example using Split it works just fine.

Comment: I figured it out using your code. I just had to place it outside of the method that was doing the work while it built the string.